# multiple IS NOT NULL with OR operator

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Does anyone know how to improve the below oracle sql query with multiple IS NOT NULL with OR operator:

```
  select count(1)
  from s_srv_req sr, s_evt_act act, s_bu bu
  where sr.row_id = act.sra_sr_id(+)
  and sr.bu_id = bu.row_id
  and sr.last_upd > to_date('31-DEC-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
  and **(X_REASON_CODE1 is not null 
        OR X_REASON_CODE2 is not null 
        OR X_CONCERN_CODE1 is not null 
        OR X_CONCERN_CODE2 is not null 
        OR X_COMPONENT_CODE is not null)**
```

The purpose here is to fetch all records even if one of the codes column is not null.
Note: This query is taking much time and i cannot progress with such time taking queries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you established that the `is not null` and `or` are what is actually slowing it down? What does the execution plan show? (Also, please consider using ANSI join syntax).

Comment: Do you have indexes on all of the code columns and join columns?

Comment: Check all the columns in the WHERE clause to see if they have indexes.

Comment: Which table are the `X_REASON_CODE1`, `X_REASON_CODE2`, `X_CONCERN_CODE1`, `X_CONCERN_CODE2`, and `X_COMPONENT_CODE` fields on?

Comment: Code columns are present in S_SRV_REQ table. There are no indexes on these code columns and its not possible to create one. Without the code columns conditions, query was taking 2 hrs to complete, with the code columns query seems never ending!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use COALESCE function

```
select count(1)
  from s_srv_req sr, s_evt_act act, s_bu bu
  where sr.row_id = act.sra_sr_id(+)
       and sr.bu_id = bu.row_id
       and sr.last_upd > to_date('31-DEC-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')
       and  COALESCE(X_REASON_CODE1, X_REASON_CODE2, X_CONCERN_CODE1, X_CONCERN_CODE2, X_COMPONENT_CODE) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with using a excluding method?
Use the total table to minus the records that all of those columns are null at the same time?
here are some fake code:

Method1, using Minus

```
table a
minus
table a with X_REASON_CODE1 || 
        OR X_REASON_CODE2 ||
        OR X_CONCERN_CODE1 || 
        OR X_CONCERN_CODE2 || 
        OR X_COMPONENT_CODE is not null
```

Method 2, using NOT EXISTS or NOT IN

```
table a
not exists X_REASON_CODE1 || 
        OR X_REASON_CODE2 ||
        OR X_CONCERN_CODE1 || 
        OR X_CONCERN_CODE2 || 
        OR X_COMPONENT_CODE is not null
```